# Remove current row from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have list view which is binding with `ObservableCollection`. I want to delete selected row in the list view from `ObservableCollection` on a button click.

How i can get selected row position? My collection does not contains ID

You can see the code i'm using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831315/problem-when-filling-listview-with-observablecollection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have regular classes (no override of Equals) then you can simply Remove it:

```
 myCollection.Remove(Listbox1.Selecteditem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) of your ListView:

```
myCollection.RemoveAt(Listbox1.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: A tip: *how* would he use it? Or in my case i want to do the same thing; what would i do with the `SelectedIndex` property?

Comment: The OP asked for selected row position which I assumed he meant index of selected item, which is SelectedIndex. Don't know anything about your case, post as new question if different.

Comment: i meant literally.  `myCollection.Remove(Listbox1.SelectedIndex);` ?

Comment: IList<T> has a void RemoveAt(int index) method which ObservableCollection implements.

Comment: So `myCollection.RemoveAt(Listbox1.SelectedIndex);` ?